# CXF JAXRS - How do I pass Date as QueryParam

Tags: java, rest, service, cxf, jax-rs

I have a service defined as follows.

`public String getData(@QueryParam("date") Date date)`

I'm trying to pass a `java.util.Date` to it from my client (which is jaxrs:client of CXF, not a generic HTTP client or browser).

My service receives the date as `Thu Mar 01 22:33:10 IST 2012` in the HTTP URL. Since CXF won't be able to create a `Date` object using this String, my client receives a 404 error.
I tried using a `ParameterHandler` on the service side, but I still can't parse it successfully because I'm not expecting the date in any specific format.

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583973/jax-rs-jersey-how-to-customize-error-handling), passing a `Date` is supposed to work out of the box, but I can't seem to get the basic case working. Am I required to do anything in order to successfully pass a Date object from my client to service? Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `results in the date being sent as Thu Mar 01 22:33:10 IST 2012`, since you are *recieving* a date, not *sending* one. Make sure that the URL you are calling is properly encoded before invoking it.

Comment: Edited the post to clarify. The URL is properly encoded. My client is sending the date parameter as `Thu Mar 01 22:33:10 IST 2012` and my service is also receiving it as-is. However, the date is in a format which can not be parsed (if I use a ParameterHandler) or which can not be used by CXF to directly create a Date object.

Comment: That makes things clearer. Which leads to the next question - is this method expected to also be able to handle dates in other (more standard) formats?

Comment: Actually, I do not care about the date format at all. It is sufficient as long as I'm able to pass a `Date` object across, the format used internally can be anything. If it helps, I do not mind internally using a specific format (such as yyyyMMddHHmmSS).

Comment: Actually, I was asking in order to better determine a solution to handling the ***incoming*** date. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The problem is that JAX-RS dictates that parameter unbundling be done in one of two ways:

1. The parameter bean has a public constructor that accepts a String
2. The parameter bean has a static `valueOf(String)` method.

In your case, the Date is being unbundled via its `Date(String)` constructor, which cannot handle the input format your client is sending. You have a couple options available to remedy this:

---

***Option 1***

Get your client to change the format of the date before they send it. This is the ideal, but probably the hardest to accomplish!

---

***Option 2***

Handle the crazy date format. The options for this are:

***Change your method signature to accept a string. Attempt to construct a Date object out of that and if that fails, use your own custom SimpleDateFormat class to parse it.***

```
static final DateFormat CRAZY_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("");

public String getData(@QueryParam("date") String dateString) {
    final Date date;
    try {
        date = new Date(dateString); // yes, I know this is a deprecated method
    } catch(Exception e) {
        date = CRAZY_FORMAT.parse(dateString);
    }
}
```

***Define your own parameter class that does the logic mentioned above. Give it a string constructor or static `valueOf(String)` method that invokes the logic. And an additional method to get the Date when all is said and done.***

```
public class DateParameter implements Serializable {
    public static DateParameter valueOf(String dateString) {
        try {
            date = new Date(dateString); // yes, I know this is a deprecated method
        } catch(Exception e) {
            date = CRAZY_FORMAT.parse(dateString);
        }
    }

    private Date date;
    // Constructor, Getters, Setters
}

public String getData(@QueryParam("date") DateParameter dateParam) {
    final Date date = dateParam.getDate();
}
```

***Or finally, you can register a parameter handler for dates. Where its logic is simply the same as mentioned for the other options above. Note that you need to be using at least CXF 2.5.3 in order to have your parameter handler evaluated before it tries the default unbundling logic.***

```
public class DateHandler implements ParameterHandler<Date> {
    public Map fromString(String s) {
        final Date date;
        try {
            date = new Date(dateString); // yes, I know this is a deprecated method
        } catch(Exception e) {
            date = CRAZY_FORMAT.parse(dateString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reg. Option #1: In this case I'm distributing the client myself to users, so I'm free to choose a fixed date format if that helps. But the question is, how do I do this exactly? What determines which format the CXF client would use? I'd still to keep the `java.util.Date` as the `QueryParam` instead of changing to  `String` or another `DateParam` like object to encapsulate a `Date` object inside.

Comment: Well if you have control over the client that makes things better. Just pass in any date format that can be handled by the `Date(String)` constructor. An example would be '12/20/2005 09:30:00 +0100' (mm/dd/yyy HH:MM:ss Z).

Comment: I do have control over the client, but my signature on both client & service side should be `Date`. Since on the client side, CXF **internally** calls `toString()` on my `Date` object while constructing the query parameters, how do I exercise my control and say use a specific date format and not the default one? Are you suggesting to extend `Date` and override `toString()` (which means the client signature will change)? Or is there any other mechanism which can be used on both client & service side to override the behavior? I guess `MessageBodyReader/Wrtier` is meant only for request body.

Comment: I have finally used `ParameterHandler` (third approach in Option 2). Since I have control on the client, I am directly parsing using the CRAZY_FORMAT (used by `Date.toString()`). Thanks Perception.

Comment: Just remember that SimpleDateFormat is NOT thread safe and putting 'static final' is wrong

Comment: What is the problem in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZCXF.png) case? This format supports the Date constructor.

Answer (score 20):

[Percepiton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9522619/4173303) was very useful, but `ParameterHandler` has been deprecated in Apache-cxf 3.0, see the [Apache-cxf 3.0 Migration Guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/30-migration-guide.html):

> CXF JAX-RS ParameterHandler has been dropped, please use JAX-RS 2.0 ParamConverterProvider.

So I add an example with the `ParamConverterProvider` :

```
public class DateParameterConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> type, Type type1, Annotation[] antns) {
        if (Date.class.equals(type)) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ParamConverter<T> paramConverter = (ParamConverter<T>) new DateParameterConverter();
            return paramConverter;
        }
        return null;
    }

}

public class DateParameterConverter implements ParamConverter<Date> {

    public static final String format = "yyyy-MM-dd"; // set the format to whatever you need

    @Override
    public Date fromString(String string) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            return simpleDateFormat.parse(string);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Date t) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(t);
    }

}
```

The `@SuppressWarnings` is required to suppress an "unchecked or unsafe operations" warning during compilation. See [How do I address unchecked cast warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings) for more details.

The `ParamConverterProvider` can be registred as provider. Here is how I did it:

```
  <jaxrs:server id="myService" address="/rest">
      <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
           ...
      </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

      <jaxrs:providers>
          <ref bean="dateParameterConverterProvider" />
      </jaxrs:providers>
  </jaxrs:server>

  <bean id="dateParameterConverterProvider" class="myPackage.DateParameterConverterProvider"/>
```

See [Apache-cxf JAX-RS : Services Configuration](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-web.xml)  for more information.

Comment: Great answer! I use `@Provider` annotation in `DateParameterConverter` instead of xml configuration. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom DateParam class seems the safest option. You can then base your method signatures on that and implement the ugly conversion logic inside the valueOf() method or the class constructor. It is also more self-documenting than using plain strings

Answer (score 0):

As `@Perception` suggests in option two, you can handle the date. But you should use following:

```
private Date getDateFromString(String dateString) {
    try {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = df.parse(dateString);
        return date;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //WebApplicationException ...("Date format should be yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Status.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

You call it from within the resource as

```
Date date = getDateFromString(dateString);//dateString is query param.
```