# Custom JSON Date handling in CXF

Tags: java, json, cxf, jax-rs, jettison

I'm using apache CXF to create a JAX-RS service that consumes multipart/form-data, one of the parts is `application/json` which I'm handling in a Java bean. The problem that I have is that the date format being passed in is not recognised by the standard jettison deserialiser and I just get `null`.

The service is:

```
@POST
@Path("/blah/")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public String doBlah(MultipartBody body)
{
        JSON json = atts.get(0).getObject(JSON.class);
}
```

The JSON object is:

```
class JSON {
    Date date;
}
```

The date passed in is something like: `November 25, 2012 13:35:24` which i know how to convert using `SimpleDateFormat`, so I can change the JSON to have a string and i get the value and can then manually do the conversion ... BUT how do you register a class in CXF to do the conversion in jettison?

Is there a config in beans.xml or something where i can add a custom handler and/or override the default `Date` handling?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520716/cxf-jaxrs-how-do-i-pass-date-as-queryparam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a custom date handler in Spring as follows:

```
<jaxrs:server …>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class='….DateHandler' />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

The date handler class itself can be pretty simple:

```
public class DateHandler implements ParameterHandler<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date fromString(String s) {
        Date ret = // do your magic
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working for deserializing json? should it be (i may have some config issues?)

Comment: It does for me, although I should note that I'm using the Jackson JSON processor (`<bean class='org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider' />`)