# Pass java date into rest query parameter

Tags: java, rest

I have

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}")
public Response modify(@PathParam("id") Integer id, 
                       @QueryParam("user") String user, @QueryParam("time") Date time) {....
```

I am trying to use RestClient to call this web service (the above is actually a cut down version of what I have)

When I call

```
..../123?user=user1
```

I hit the web service. As soon as I add time I get a 403 Forbidden message

```
..../123?user=user1&time=2013-09-10T20:00:00Z
```

Even if I pass nothing into the time query parameter I get the 403.

Is there anything difference about passing the java dates?

Thank in advance

Comment: Have a look at this this question and accepted solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520716/cxf-jaxrs-how-do-i-pass-date-as-queryparam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not able to deserialize the `String` to a `Date`. Two options are either you can modify the date string as accepted by the date class or use another form, such as a `long` value.

Answer (score 0):

One observation: It seems you are adding an extra slash(/) before your query params:

change this

```
..../123/?user=user1&time=2013-09-10T20:00:00Z
```

to

```
..../123?user=user1&time=2013-09-10T20:00:00Z
```

Second thing is that you may have to encode your URL to send the date properly to server

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the Party !! But I think this will help others 
 I was able to make it work by changing `Date` to `LocalDateTime` and using `@DateTimeFormat`

Worked fine with this requestURI

`/test/123?user=user1&time=2013-09-10T20:00:00Z`

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> modify(@PathParam("id") Integer id,
            @RequestParam(name = "user", required = false) String user,
            @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) @RequestParam("time") LocalDateTime date) {
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Comment: DateTimeFormat is an annotation specific to Spring, which you do not mention in your answer. The question seems to be about generic Java EE/Jakarte EE.